# python fatest way to iterate compare two dictionary values

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, ipython

I have two dictionaries

```
user_hash = {
"as34": "98354897394053452345",
"ad23" : "2131313111313131313",
"ae23": "31245512121521212121"
}


 active_user_hash =  [
   {"field0": "231634684712313"}, 
   {"field0" : "23145454564120"}, 
   {"field0" : "215465464133313"}]
```

In reality, there are millions key value pair in these dictionaries and list of dictionaries. The aim is to loop through EACH value of dictionary 1 and compare it with the second list of dictionary's value using a custom function. I cannot use any kind of sorting or optimization of this logic as each element-to-element comparison is necessary. Which is the fastest way to do this?

Current loop takes 11 mins! I want to reduce it to seconds.

```
    for index, id_hash in user_hash.iteritems():
        try:
            for element in active_user_hash:

                match = custom_comparison_function_algo(id_hash, element['field0'])
                if match < 40:
                    print 'success'

        except Exception as err:
            print err

import distance

def custom_comparison_function_algo(hash1, hash2):

    levenshtein_dist = distance.nlevenshtein(hash1, hash2, method=1)
    jaccard_dist = distance.jaccard(hash1, hash2)
    return int(((levenshtein_dist + jaccard_dist) / 2) * 100)
```

I have tried numpy vectorization but could not wrap my head around it.

Comment: how about constructing `sets` from the `values`, getting their intersection and finally inversely looking up the `keys`?

Comment: The possibilities of succesful vectorization are entirely dependent on the internals of your custom_comparison_function_algo

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Would make sense if the hashes were all unique.

Comment: Actually, OP, do you want to find out which key it belongs to? Or whether there was a match?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ These hashes look sufficiently big as to not worry about collisions within millions but theoretically, sure. Also the check OP is doing is more sofisticated so..

Comment: All the hashes are unique. The custom_comparison_function_algo uses distance python library. I want to get the match as well as the key .

Comment: What is `distance`?

Comment: I'm not really sure if there is any sensible approach to solve this problem. If you have `n` hashes and `m` comparison objects and do Levenstein and Jaccard distance (their runtime depends on the string- length, say `k`) you'll end up with a `n*m*k` runtime. With `n` and `m` being on the order of millions and the string length being 20 you'll end up with several tens of trillions of operations...

Comment: why are you doing distance matching on hashes? the whole point of hashing is to avoid this...

Comment: wouldnt this be a case (lotsa loops) where something like [Cython](http://cython.org/) can really make a difference?

Comment: What's the speed of the distance calc?  numpy 'vectoriztion' won't help with dictionary iteration. Cython probably won't either.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a list  (or a set as proposed by Ev. Kounis) from values of active_user_hash dictionaries, and then run your functions in list comprehension?

```
  search_in = [ x.values()[0] for x in active_user_hash ]
  res = [ x in search_in for x in user_hash.values() ]
```